# Add JavaScript and jQuery to SharePoint in one page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I open My `Editform.aspx` page with SharePoint Designer and I want to add javascript code to it. This is the code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a").click(function(){
    $("#content").hide();
  });
  $("#b").click(function(){
    $("#content").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

How can I add and place  it to one SharePoint page?

Comment: If you just want it on one page, add a content editor webpart (for 2010), or script editor webpart (in 2013)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/how-to-add-script-to-page?rq=1 , http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40807/how-to-add-some-javascript-code-to-all-the-aspx-pages-not-just-on-web-parts?rq=1 , http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114966/add-javascript-to-sharepoint-2013 (which is itself a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114954/put-a-javascript-to-sharepoint) ... take your pick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it into the `<HEAD></HEAD>` tag via SharePoint designer, or I prefer to edit the page via the web UI, and add a Script Web part, HTML Form or Content Editor web part and throw the code in there (each web part has a unique method to adding code)